# Who to map through a nested object and delete a key value pair in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an `array` of objects and I am trying to create a new object but with out a particular `key:value` pair in it. Here is my object.

```js
{
  "versionRoomPoolList": [{
      "pmsRoomType": ["CITY"],
      "versionRoomTypeAttributeList": [{
          "attributeDisplayId": 2,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "CV",
          "attributeDescription": "City View"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 6,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "HF",
          "attributeDescription": "High Floor, 8th floor and above"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 4,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "KN",
          "attributeDescription": "1 King Bed"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 5,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "NE",
          "attributeDescription": "Near Elevator"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 7,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "RF",
          "attributeDescription": "Mobile Lock"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 3,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "SB",
          "attributeDescription": "Sofabed"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 1,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "SU",
          "attributeDescription": "Alpine Guest Room"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 8,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "TS",
          "attributeDescription": "Separate Shower and Bathtub"
        }
      ],
      "roomTypeDisplayId": 31,
      "roomTypeId": 21,
      "roomTypeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "roomPool": "CITY",
      "maxOccupancyStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "currentMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "capacityStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newCapacity": 12,
      "currentCapacity": 12,
      "guaranteed": 9,
      "minAvailability": 1,
      "premium": false,
      "eliteAvailability": false,
      "isROH": false
    },
    {
      "versionRoomTypeList": [{
          "pmsRoomType": ["HOSP"],
          "versionRoomTypeAttributeList": [{
              "attributeDisplayId": 2,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "CV",
              "attributeDescription": "City View"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 5,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "HF",
              "attributeDescription": "High Floor, 8th floor and above"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 1,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "HS",
              "attributeDescription": "Hospitality Suite"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 4,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "KN",
              "attributeDescription": "1 King Bed"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 6,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "RF",
              "attributeDescription": "Mobile Lock"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 3,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "SB",
              "attributeDescription": "Sofabed"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 7,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "TS",
              "attributeDescription": "Separate Shower and Bathtub"
            }
          ],
          "roomTypeDisplayId": 34,
          "roomTypeId": 24,
          "roomTypeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "roomPool": "HOSP",
          "maxOccupancyStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "newMaxOccupancy": 4,
          "currentMaxOccupancy": 4,
          "capacityStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "newCapacity": 1,
          "currentCapacity": 1,
          "guaranteed": 1,
          "minAvailability": 1,
          "premium": true,
          "eliteAvailability": false,
          "isROH": true
        },
        {
          "pmsRoomType": ["HOSP"],
          "versionRoomTypeAttributeList": [{
              "attributeDisplayId": 2,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "CV",
              "attributeDescription": "City View"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 6,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "HF",
              "attributeDescription": "High Floor, 8th floor and above"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 1,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "HS",
              "attributeDescription": "Hospitality Suite"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 4,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "KN",
              "attributeDescription": "1 King Bed"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 5,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "NE",
              "attributeDescription": "Near Elevator"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 7,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "RF",
              "attributeDescription": "Mobile Lock"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 3,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "SB",
              "attributeDescription": "Sofabed"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 8,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "TS",
              "attributeDescription": "Separate Shower and Bathtub"
            }
          ],
          "roomTypeDisplayId": 35,
          "roomTypeId": 25,
          "roomTypeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "roomPool": "HOSP",
          "maxOccupancyStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "newMaxOccupancy": 4,
          "currentMaxOccupancy": 4,
          "capacityStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "newCapacity": 1,
          "currentCapacity": 1,
          "guaranteed": 1,
          "minAvailability": 1,
          "premium": true,
          "eliteAvailability": false,
          "isROH": false
        }
      ],
      "roomPoolDisplayId": 4,
      "roomPoolStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "roomPoolCode": "HOSP",
      "miosSRC": "YD",
      "sna": "N",
      "maxOccupancyStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "currentMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "capacityStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newCapacity": 2,
      "currentCapacity": 2,
      "premium": true,
      "eliteAvailability": false,
      "excludeAlways": false,
      "excludeOverAuth": false,
      "propertySellOnly": false
    },
    {
      "pmsRoomType": ["HOSP"],
      "versionRoomTypeAttributeList": [{
          "attributeDisplayId": 2,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "CV",
          "attributeDescription": "City View"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 5,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "HF",
          "attributeDescription": "High Floor, 8th floor and above"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 1,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "HS",
          "attributeDescription": "Hospitality Suite"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 4,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "KN",
          "attributeDescription": "1 King Bed"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 6,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "RF",
          "attributeDescription": "Mobile Lock"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 3,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "SB",
          "attributeDescription": "Sofabed"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 7,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "TS",
          "attributeDescription": "Separate Shower and Bathtub"
        }
      ],
      "roomTypeDisplayId": 34,
      "roomTypeId": 24,
      "roomTypeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "roomPool": "HOSP",
      "maxOccupancyStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "currentMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "capacityStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newCapacity": 1,
      "currentCapacity": 1,
      "guaranteed": 1,
      "minAvailability": 1,
      "premium": true,
      "eliteAvailability": false,
      "isROH": true
    }
  ]
}
```

So what I am trying to do is remove the `pmsRoomType` in each of the objects.

Here is what I wrote as part of a bigger method I wrote to try and address this.

```js
var data = {
  versionRoomPoolList: array.map(roompools, function(roompool) {
    roompool = lang.mixin({}, roompool);
    delete roompool.numAttributeChars;
    delete roompool.pmsRoomType;
    delete roompool.versionRoomTypeList[0].pmsRoomType;
    return roompool;
  })
};
```

However I keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I am assuming I need to write another `.map` method but I am stuck on how to do that or is that the correct way?

Comment: It looks like not every object in the array has a `versionRoomTypeList` property, hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You data is not an array, it is an object with `versionRoomPoolList` field.

`map` function calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results.

I think this is what are you looking for: Create new object (`data`) with `versionRoomPoolList` as key and an new array as value.

```
var rawData = {
  "versionRoomPoolList": [
    {
      "pmsRoomType": [
        "CITY"
      ],
      "versionRoomTypeAttributeList": [
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 2,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "CV",
          "attributeDescription": "City View"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 6,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "HF",
          "attributeDescription": "High Floor, 8th floor and above"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 4,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "KN",
          "attributeDescription": "1 King Bed"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 5,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "NE",
          "attributeDescription": "Near Elevator"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 7,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "RF",
          "attributeDescription": "Mobile Lock"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 3,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "SB",
          "attributeDescription": "Sofabed"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 1,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "SU",
          "attributeDescription": "Alpine Guest Room"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 8,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "TS",
          "attributeDescription": "Separate Shower and Bathtub"
        }
      ],
      "roomTypeDisplayId": 31,
      "roomTypeId": 21,
      "roomTypeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "roomPool": "CITY",
      "maxOccupancyStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "currentMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "capacityStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newCapacity": 12,
      "currentCapacity": 12,
      "guaranteed": 9,
      "minAvailability": 1,
      "premium": false,
      "eliteAvailability": false,
      "isROH": false
    },
    {
      "versionRoomTypeList": [
        {
          "pmsRoomType": [
            "HOSP"
          ],
          "versionRoomTypeAttributeList": [
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 2,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "CV",
              "attributeDescription": "City View"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 5,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "HF",
              "attributeDescription": "High Floor, 8th floor and above"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 1,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "HS",
              "attributeDescription": "Hospitality Suite"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 4,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "KN",
              "attributeDescription": "1 King Bed"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 6,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "RF",
              "attributeDescription": "Mobile Lock"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 3,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "SB",
              "attributeDescription": "Sofabed"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 7,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "TS",
              "attributeDescription": "Separate Shower and Bathtub"
            }
          ],
          "roomTypeDisplayId": 34,
          "roomTypeId": 24,
          "roomTypeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "roomPool": "HOSP",
          "maxOccupancyStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "newMaxOccupancy": 4,
          "currentMaxOccupancy": 4,
          "capacityStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "newCapacity": 1,
          "currentCapacity": 1,
          "guaranteed": 1,
          "minAvailability": 1,
          "premium": true,
          "eliteAvailability": false,
          "isROH": true
        },
        {
          "pmsRoomType": [
            "HOSP"
          ],
          "versionRoomTypeAttributeList": [
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 2,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "CV",
              "attributeDescription": "City View"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 6,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "HF",
              "attributeDescription": "High Floor, 8th floor and above"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 1,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "HS",
              "attributeDescription": "Hospitality Suite"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 4,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "KN",
              "attributeDescription": "1 King Bed"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 5,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "NE",
              "attributeDescription": "Near Elevator"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 7,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "RF",
              "attributeDescription": "Mobile Lock"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 3,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "SB",
              "attributeDescription": "Sofabed"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 8,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "TS",
              "attributeDescription": "Separate Shower and Bathtub"
            }
          ],
          "roomTypeDisplayId": 35,
          "roomTypeId": 25,
          "roomTypeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "roomPool": "HOSP",
          "maxOccupancyStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "newMaxOccupancy": 4,
          "currentMaxOccupancy": 4,
          "capacityStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "newCapacity": 1,
          "currentCapacity": 1,
          "guaranteed": 1,
          "minAvailability": 1,
          "premium": true,
          "eliteAvailability": false,
          "isROH": false
        }
      ],
      "roomPoolDisplayId": 4,
      "roomPoolStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "roomPoolCode": "HOSP",
      "miosSRC": "YD",
      "sna": "N",
      "maxOccupancyStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "currentMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "capacityStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newCapacity": 2,
      "currentCapacity": 2,
      "premium": true,
      "eliteAvailability": false,
      "excludeAlways": false,
      "excludeOverAuth": false,
      "propertySellOnly": false
    },
    {
      "pmsRoomType": [
        "HOSP"
      ],
      "versionRoomTypeAttributeList": [
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 2,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "CV",
          "attributeDescription": "City View"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 5,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "HF",
          "attributeDescription": "High Floor, 8th floor and above"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 1,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "HS",
          "attributeDescription": "Hospitality Suite"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 4,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "KN",
          "attributeDescription": "1 King Bed"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 6,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "RF",
          "attributeDescription": "Mobile Lock"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 3,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "SB",
          "attributeDescription": "Sofabed"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 7,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "TS",
          "attributeDescription": "Separate Shower and Bathtub"
        }
      ],
      "roomTypeDisplayId": 34,
      "roomTypeId": 24,
      "roomTypeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "roomPool": "HOSP",
      "maxOccupancyStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "currentMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "capacityStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newCapacity": 1,
      "currentCapacity": 1,
      "guaranteed": 1,
      "minAvailability": 1,
      "premium": true,
      "eliteAvailability": false,
      "isROH": true
    }
  ]
}

var data = {
  versionRoomPoolList: rawData.versionRoomPoolList.map(function(roompool) {
    roompool = Object.assign({}, roompool);
    delete roompool.numAttributeChars;
    delete roompool.pmsRoomType;
    // make sure `versionRoomTypeList` is existed
    roompool.versionRoomTypeList && delete roompool.versionRoomTypeList[0].pmsRoomType;
    return roompool;
  })
};
console.log(data)
```

Comment: I cannot use rawData because I am getting this data from an endpoint. So can you adjust the method.

Comment: Set your response to a variable called `rawData`, or you can warrap my logic to a function by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
const data = {
  "versionRoomPoolList": [{
      "pmsRoomType": ["CITY"],
      "versionRoomTypeAttributeList": [{
          "attributeDisplayId": 2,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "CV",
          "attributeDescription": "City View"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 6,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "HF",
          "attributeDescription": "High Floor, 8th floor and above"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 4,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "KN",
          "attributeDescription": "1 King Bed"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 5,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "NE",
          "attributeDescription": "Near Elevator"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 7,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "RF",
          "attributeDescription": "Mobile Lock"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 3,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "SB",
          "attributeDescription": "Sofabed"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 1,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "SU",
          "attributeDescription": "Alpine Guest Room"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 8,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "TS",
          "attributeDescription": "Separate Shower and Bathtub"
        }
      ],
      "roomTypeDisplayId": 31,
      "roomTypeId": 21,
      "roomTypeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "roomPool": "CITY",
      "maxOccupancyStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "currentMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "capacityStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newCapacity": 12,
      "currentCapacity": 12,
      "guaranteed": 9,
      "minAvailability": 1,
      "premium": false,
      "eliteAvailability": false,
      "isROH": false
    },
    {
      "versionRoomTypeList": [{
          "pmsRoomType": ["HOSP"],
          "versionRoomTypeAttributeList": [{
              "attributeDisplayId": 2,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "CV",
              "attributeDescription": "City View"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 5,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "HF",
              "attributeDescription": "High Floor, 8th floor and above"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 1,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "HS",
              "attributeDescription": "Hospitality Suite"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 4,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "KN",
              "attributeDescription": "1 King Bed"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 6,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "RF",
              "attributeDescription": "Mobile Lock"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 3,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "SB",
              "attributeDescription": "Sofabed"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 7,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "TS",
              "attributeDescription": "Separate Shower and Bathtub"
            }
          ],
          "roomTypeDisplayId": 34,
          "roomTypeId": 24,
          "roomTypeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "roomPool": "HOSP",
          "maxOccupancyStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "newMaxOccupancy": 4,
          "currentMaxOccupancy": 4,
          "capacityStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "newCapacity": 1,
          "currentCapacity": 1,
          "guaranteed": 1,
          "minAvailability": 1,
          "premium": true,
          "eliteAvailability": false,
          "isROH": true
        },
        {
          "pmsRoomType": ["HOSP"],
          "versionRoomTypeAttributeList": [{
              "attributeDisplayId": 2,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "CV",
              "attributeDescription": "City View"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 6,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "HF",
              "attributeDescription": "High Floor, 8th floor and above"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 1,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "HS",
              "attributeDescription": "Hospitality Suite"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 4,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "KN",
              "attributeDescription": "1 King Bed"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 5,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "NE",
              "attributeDescription": "Near Elevator"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 7,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "RF",
              "attributeDescription": "Mobile Lock"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 3,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "SB",
              "attributeDescription": "Sofabed"
            },
            {
              "attributeDisplayId": 8,
              "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
              "attributeCode": "TS",
              "attributeDescription": "Separate Shower and Bathtub"
            }
          ],
          "roomTypeDisplayId": 35,
          "roomTypeId": 25,
          "roomTypeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "roomPool": "HOSP",
          "maxOccupancyStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "newMaxOccupancy": 4,
          "currentMaxOccupancy": 4,
          "capacityStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "newCapacity": 1,
          "currentCapacity": 1,
          "guaranteed": 1,
          "minAvailability": 1,
          "premium": true,
          "eliteAvailability": false,
          "isROH": false
        }
      ],
      "roomPoolDisplayId": 4,
      "roomPoolStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "roomPoolCode": "HOSP",
      "miosSRC": "YD",
      "sna": "N",
      "maxOccupancyStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "currentMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "capacityStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newCapacity": 2,
      "currentCapacity": 2,
      "premium": true,
      "eliteAvailability": false,
      "excludeAlways": false,
      "excludeOverAuth": false,
      "propertySellOnly": false
    },
    {
      "pmsRoomType": ["HOSP"],
      "versionRoomTypeAttributeList": [{
          "attributeDisplayId": 2,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "CV",
          "attributeDescription": "City View"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 5,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "HF",
          "attributeDescription": "High Floor, 8th floor and above"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 1,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "HS",
          "attributeDescription": "Hospitality Suite"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 4,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "KN",
          "attributeDescription": "1 King Bed"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 6,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "RF",
          "attributeDescription": "Mobile Lock"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 3,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "SB",
          "attributeDescription": "Sofabed"
        },
        {
          "attributeDisplayId": 7,
          "attributeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
          "attributeCode": "TS",
          "attributeDescription": "Separate Shower and Bathtub"
        }
      ],
      "roomTypeDisplayId": 34,
      "roomTypeId": 24,
      "roomTypeStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "roomPool": "HOSP",
      "maxOccupancyStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "currentMaxOccupancy": 4,
      "capacityStatus": "NOCHANGE",
      "newCapacity": 1,
      "currentCapacity": 1,
      "guaranteed": 1,
      "minAvailability": 1,
      "premium": true,
      "eliteAvailability": false,
      "isROH": true
    }
  ]
}

const myFunction = data => ({
  ...data,
  versionRoomPoolList: data.versionRoomPoolList.filter(i => {
    delete i.pmsRoomType;
    return i;
  }),
});

console.log(myFunction(data))
```

Comment: I've updated my code with a code snippet where you can test it. The example will remove all pmsRoomType key from each object.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use this because I am cannot use a tool like `babel` to transpile my code. This particular functionally has to support `IE7` and `IE8` for an internal business application.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mostly correct and as Felix Kling commented on your post, you just need to safeguard against properties that don't exist. This can be as simple as:

```
if (roompool.versionRoomTypeList && roompool.versionRoomTypeList.length) {
  // delete
}
```

That said... I'm suspecting that you just have a typo and you should change `versionRoomTypeList` to `versionRoomTypeAttributeList` :-P